# Scoped views do not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have read all stackoverflow posts and the document on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise concerning the scoped Devise views in a Rails application.

I have a single model Admin. Later I am planning to add other models such as User. My problem is that my scoped views do not work. Here is what I have done:

I modified the file `config/initializers/devise.rb`: added `config.scoped_views = true`.

Then I generated a session view (using `rails g devise:views -v sessions`) `new.html.erb`, modified it and put this file in the folder `app/views/admins/sessions`.

I restarted the Rails server and followed the `http://0.0.0.0:3000/admin/sign_in`.

Nothing changed.

Then I put the file `new.html.erb` into the folder `app/views/admins/sessions/new`, again no effect.

Additional info: `routes.rb` contains `devise_for :admin`.

Does anyone have idea what I am missing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `devise_for :admins` in routes.rb ?

Comment: You are right. Didn't pay attention. Actually I left `devise_for :admin` as it is (since the admin is one), but changed `app/views/admins/sessions` to the singular version `app/views/ admin/sessions`. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Np. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route should be

```
devise_for :admins
```

If you want to keep the route, Change the view folder to `app/views/admin/`

Comment: The problem was that while my route was `devise_for :admin` I put my views into the `views/admins` not `views/admin`. Completely forgot that I used the singular version.